# Embed website in adobe animate swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, iframe, jquery-animate

First of all, I am fairly new to programming. 
I am currently working on an app for a touchscreen-based infoscreen.
I looked through all of google already and can't seem to find anything on that, so i am hoping anyone here could give me a push into the right direction.

I am working in Adobe Animate, from where I plan to export the whole app when it's finished. My Problem is, i need to embed the customers Website in this app somehow, and failed doing so for the last few days.

**I am looking for something like an iFrame to load the website-url into.**

I heard about the htmlloader, but until now i couldn't figure out a way to get this to work, and i am not too sure about it being the right way.

As I said, it's the first project I am doing with Animate/Flash and actionscript, so I would really appreciate your help.
Please let me know if you need any additional information on the project, maybe i forgot to mention something important.

best regards,
Flo

Comment: The first place to go for examples about Flash is, suddenly, the official online documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html#includeExamplesSummary

Comment: This is an AIR project, right? You're making a real installable app, not just loading output swf in browsers?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot load a webpage inside of flash the way you're thinking.  Flash has extremely basic HTML support (version 3, if I recall), so anything rendered would look like 1997.  WebKit browsers have come a long way in web technologies; Flash has not.

Your best bet is to launch the webpage with [`navigateToURL()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL()), which will open the link in the installed browser of choice.

```
import flash.net.*;
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.adobe.com"));
```

Comment: Wrong. **HTMLLoader** and **StageWebView**.

Comment: **@Organis:** Those only work for Adobe AIR, and are not available for standard Flash.

Comment: Correct. Because in the browser you can access the outside world via **ExternalInterface** and show any HTML content you want. I think you should extend your answer so it is more informative and educating.